# Replacing all values in a column from csv file using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a csv file with mix of string and numbers in different columns. I want to replace all "?" characters form column C.

I am trying the following:

```
Set wb_dst = Workbooks.Open("C:\myFile.csv")
Set ws_dst = wb_dst.Sheets(1)
values = ws_dst.Range("C1:c500").Value
values = Replace(values, "?", "")
```

But not sure how to dump this value back to `column C` without replacing values in other columns. Or, is there any other way to perform the above task or replacing certain characters only in a certain column from a csv file on local drive?

Edit:
I am looking to update the values in column C for myFile.csv so I suppose I have to dump data to column C, I am not sure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simple. You just assign the array you took from the range back to the value of that same range after modification. However, the idea of `values = Replace(values, "?", "")` won't fly. You will need to modify each element of the array individually.

```
Sub Macro1()

    Const LookFor       As String = "?"
    Const Replacement   As String = "X"
    
    Dim Wb              As Workbook
    Dim Ws              As Worksheet
    Dim Rng             As Range
    Dim Arr             As Variant
    Dim R               As Long                 ' loop counter: rows
    
    Set Wb = Workbooks.Open("C:\myFile.csv")
    Set Ws = Wb.Worksheets(1)
    Set Rng = Ws.Range("C1:C500")
    
    Arr = Rng.Value
    For R = 1 To UBound(Arr)
        Arr(R, 1) = Replace(Arr(R, 1), LookFor, Replacement)
    Next R
    Rng.Value = Arr
End Sub
```

Comment: Does it dump data back to CSV or is your code missing that part as goal is to get the csv updated with new values for column C

Comment: There is no "CVS". The CVS file was opened in Excel and the workbook created from it was assigned to the variable `Wb`. That workbook's Worksheet(1) was then modified. You can then decide to save the workbook or not, in xlsx, xlsx or cvs format. Record the `SaveAs` keystrokes with the macro recorder and add the VBA commands to the above code.at the bottom.

Comment: You might also open the CVS file in `NotePad` and use the *Edit > Replace* function there to directly replace values in the CVS file without going through Excel.

Comment: I never used CVS :)

Comment: I also don't understand your comment regarding saveas

Comment: Sorry about the typo :-) Did you try opening the CSV file with Notepad? When you save a workbook you get to choose the format you want to save it as. I don't know if a workbook that was created from a CSV file will be saved back in CSV format automatically. The default is XLSX. You should deal with that question manually before you encode it. But if you do want code for it the macro recorder will provide the syntax.